# Implementing pImpl with minimal amount of code

Tags: c++, boost, pimpl-idiom

What kind of tricks can be used to minimize the workload of implementing pImpl classes?

Header:

```
class Foo {
    struct Impl;
    boost::scoped_ptr<Impl> self;
public:
    Foo(int arg);
    ~Foo();
    // Public member functions go here
};
```

Implementation:

```
struct Foo::Impl {
    Impl(int arg): something(arg) {}
    // All data members and private functions go here
};

Foo::Foo(int arg): self(new Impl(arg)) {}
Foo::~Foo() {}

// Foo's public functions go here (and they refer to data as self->something)
```

How would you improve this, using Boost, possibly inheritance, CRTP or other tricks to avoiding as much boilerplate code as is possible? The runtime performance is not an issue.

Comment: Actually, that doesn't implement the pimpl idiom either because you haven't fixed the copy constructor and the copy assignment `operator=` in Foo.

Comment: I don't usually need copyability (and scoped_ptr by default provides noncopyability), but you do have a point, creating those functions could be automated as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Implementation of pimpl from [Loki](http://loki-lib.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/loki-lib/loki/include/loki/Pimpl.h?view=markup) may be a good answer. See also a [DDJ Article](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/205918714?pgno=1) on this.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, but a naive implementation is not what you want.

The problem is that templates are generally inlined, the naive implementation would be:

```
template <class Object>
class Pimpl
{
public:
  explicit Pimpl(Object* obj): mObject(obj) {}
  ~Pimpl() { delete mObject; }

  // either deep copy or no copy
private:
  Object* mObject;
};
```

Now the problem is that you don't want `Object` to be known in your header file in general (not for binary compatibility, but for dependency management). And if `Object` is not known, then you cannot implement the `Destructor`, `Copy Constructor` and `Assignment Operator` directly...

The problem is far from being unsolvable however! Boost indeed has solve it for the `shared_ptr`.

The idea is to pass a second item in the constructor, that will take care of releasing the memory of the first, and that will be provided with a nice default implementation.

This works with an indirection, of course.

```
namespace detail {
  template <class Object>
  struct Deleter { virtual void do(Object*) = 0; };
}

template <class Object>
class Pimpl
{
public:
  typedef detail::Deleter<Object> deleter_type;
  typedef boost::shared_ptr<deleter_type> deleter_pointer;

  Pimpl(std::auto_ptr<Object> obj, deleter_pointer del);
  ~Pimpl();
  Pimpl(const Pimpl&);
  Pimpl& operator(const Pimpl&);

private:
  Object* mObject;
  deleter_pointer mDeleter;
};
```

It's a classic idiom in C++, add yet another level of indirection :)

Comment: Is this the smart pointer to hold the implementation? Don't boost's scoped_ptr and shared_ptr already support incomplete types?